# Facebook friends birthday returns null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting the friends info like this:

```
String fqlQuery = "select uid, name, birthday, hometown_location, about_me, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me() LIMIT 20)";
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
        Request request = new Request(currentSession, 
                "/fql", 
                params, 
                HttpMethod.GET, 
                new Request.Callback(){ 

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Got results: " + response.toString());
            }

        });
```

In Facebook permissions i have: friends_about_me, friends_birthday, friends_hometown

**logCat output:**

```
10-11 09:27:27.842: I/MainActivity(8161): Got results: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[{"uid":13962124,"birthday":null,"hometown_location":null,"pic_square":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-ash2\/1115780_13962124_1029801849_q.jpg","about_me":null,"name":"Jenny Rader"} ... etc.
```

As you can see i get the name, but not the birthday/location/about. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I execute this query in the graph explorer and take the limit out I see that about half my friend have birthday data and for the other half it comes up null. Not all data fields in the facebook graph are required and there for are not always there when graph calls are executed. My hypothesis is that birthday/location/about and not less filled in by users and there for come up null for some percentage of facebook users.

Comment: i also get the birthday, yes, sometimes its null. but why would it give me null for all friends if i asked for these privileges?

Comment: I speculate it's because you're only seeing 20 results. try getting rid of the limit and see if a few come up.